# CI/CD pending state

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

What does gitlab do in CI/CD process at pending state?

I'm using specific runner and it gets stuck at pending state for so long until running, even my internet connections work well.

Can anyone explain to me what exactly happened in CI/CD pending state?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Usually, "pending" means that all workers are in use and the next free one will be used for your CI jobs

Comment: I'm using a runner on my own and It's pending so long even none workers use it. For this reason I really want to know what happend during the pending time. Have you got any idea? @NicoHaase

Comment: it's really hard to see where your problem is since we can't see any logs from the runner. is this specific runner using your internet connection?
since you mentioned that it is on Pending state "UNTIL" running, this means that the runner does RUN, the only problem is that it really takes a long time for pending to finish.

Comment: have you tried using the public runner Gitlab offers? if so, does it also take that long to finish?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I could think of two possible reasons.

Case 1. No gitlab runner registered with your repository.
-> Solution: On your gitlab repository(project) page, go to Settings -> CI/CD -> Expand Runners sections. Then check if there are Runners associated with your repository. If there are, you need to check two things.
Check 1: Are the runners active?
Check 2: Are the tags associated with the specific runner being used as a tag in the pipeline job you are running.

Case 2. Runner cannot connect to your gitlab repository.
-> Check the network settings of your runner. Enter the runner server, and try to clone your project from there (see if it can connect to gitlab). If you are running your runner in your own PC, see if your proxy settings might be interfering with the connection.